# Oracle SQL output correct shift based on pattern

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a shift pattern that looks like this

| Mo | Tu | We | Th | Fr | Sa | Su | Mo | Tu | We | Th | Fr | Sa | Su |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D | D | D | D | D | R | R | D | D | D | D | D | R | R |

| Mo | Tu | We | Th | Fr | Sa | Su | Mo | Tu | We | Th | Fr | Sa | Su |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E | E | E | E | E | R | R | E | E | E | E | E | E | E |

the pattern code is 5D, 2R, 5E, 2R
so based on this I have a start date that will start the shift pattern
and when for ex the start date is Mar 14, 2023, when the input date is

- March 16, 2023 - the output should be D
- March 20, 2023 - should R
- March 30, 2023 - should be E
- April 3, 2023 - should be R
- April 14, 2023  - should be D again

I need an oracle sql that would output the correct shift based on the start date and input date

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data because, at the moment, the question is impossible to answer as your table appears to have 28 columns where the column names repeat 4 times (which is impossible) and then you talk about dates but your table contains no dates, only a single row with columns containing single characters.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract dates, use `mod`, assign correct shift using `case when ...`. Or write a simple function, something like:

```
create or replace function shift(i_start_date in date, i_input_date in date) 
  return varchar2 deterministic is

  v_diff int := trunc(i_input_date) - trunc(i_start_date);
  type t_list is table of varchar2(1);
  v_list t_list := t_list(
    'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'R', 'R',
    'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'R', 'R',
    'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'R', 'R',
    'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'R', 'R' );
begin
  v_diff := mod(v_diff, v_list.count) + 1;
  return v_list(v_diff);
end;
```

Test:

```
select 
    shift(date '2023-03-14', date '2023-03-01'),
    shift(date '2023-03-14', date '2023-03-20'),
    shift(date '2023-03-14', date '2023-03-30'),
    shift(date '2023-03-14', date '2023-04-03'),
    shift(date '2023-04-14', date '2023-04-14')
  from dual;
```

Returns:

```
D, R, E, R, D
```

P.S. It is not clear what to do if input date is lower than starting date, you can use `abs` or handle exception returning null, for example.

---

***...can we use only a code or pattern like 5D:2R:5E:2R?***

It is the question about splitting string into values. One of the ways is described [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/split-comma-separated-values-into-rows-in-oracle-database). So the function with pattern parameter looks like:

```
create or replace function shift(
  i_start_date in date, i_input_date in date, i_pattern in varchar2) 
  return varchar2 deterministic is

  v_diff int := trunc(i_input_date) - trunc(i_start_date);
  type t_list is table of varchar2(1);
  v_list t_list;
begin
  begin 
    with 
      p as (select level id, regexp_substr (i_pattern, '[^:]+', 1, level) val from dual
        connect by level <= length(i_pattern) - length(replace(i_pattern, ':')) + 1),
      q as (select id, regexp_substr(val, '\d*') cnt, 
                   regexp_substr(val, '[[:alpha:]]') shf from p),
      r(id, rn, cnt, shf) as (
        select id, 1, cnt, shf from q union all
        select id, rn + 1, cnt, shf from r where rn < cnt)
    select shf bulk collect into v_list from r order by id, rn;
  exception when others then
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'Unrecognized pattern');
  end;

  v_diff := mod(v_diff, v_list.count) + 1;
  return v_list(v_diff);
exception when others then 
  return null;
end;
```

Sample usage and [fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/u6ZBtojR):

```
select shift(date '2023-03-01', date '2023-03-06', '5D:2R') from dual
```

P.S.

Be careful, pattern `5D:2R:5E:2R` is not the same as `5D:2R:5D:2R:5E:2R:5E:2R` which you provided at first.

Comment: Instead of using a hardcoded table of shifts as in your function, can we use only a code or pattern like 5D:2R:5E:2R.  So when the start date is given, we can get the correct shift based on the pattern.